# Can I get the actual Menu Bar from an NSRunningApplication?

Tags: objective-c, macos, key-value-observing, nsapplication, nsrunningapplication

I'm trying to access the menu of an `NSRunningApplication` object in OS X.   it has an `ownsMenuBar` @property, however no instance of an actual menu bar (which makes sense).  I'm curious, instead, how to get access to that menu-bar that `NSRunningApplication` knows of when one exists.  KVO perhaps?  Is there any (even small) relationship between an `NSRunningApplication` and an `NSApplication`?

Thanks!

-----edit------

djai djan, you've been super helpful and here is the code i've managed to make work from your suggestions!

```
tell application "System Events"
    return menu bar of first process where frontmost is true
end tell
```

Comment: the title has nothing todo with the body

Comment: Changed it.  Sorry bout that ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no relationship between `NSRunningApplication` and `NSApplication`

BUT you can get it via applescript (which you can bridge to cocoa) **requires UI scripting**

the script is e.g.:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set m to menu bar 1 of application process "Notification Center"
end tell
```

see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/index.html

Comment: let me know if it doesnt work out right. if so, ill do some more digging